# JPEG bytes encryption returns bad image when the file is decrypted

Tags: java, android, encryption, byte, jpeg

I'm working on a simple code for encrypting the pixels of a JPEG image file. The code works well for encryption, generating a pseudo random image but when I try to decrypt it returns a not equals to original image. I'm using simple Cipher encryption (RC4).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static byte[] keyValue = {'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bitmap picture = getBitmapFromAsset("result.jpg");
    Bitmap resultPic = picture.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    picture.recycle();

    int width = resultPic.getWidth();
    int height = resultPic.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

    resultPic.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    //--------- perform encryption

    byte[] content = intArrToByteArr(pixels);

    try {

        content = decrypt(content);

    } catch (Exception e) { }

    pixels = byteArrToIntArr(content);

    //--------------------------------------------

    resultPic.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(resultPic);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/result.jpg");

    try {

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        resultPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] Data) throws Exception {

    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data);

    return encVal;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) throws Exception {

    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(encryptedData);

    return decValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "RC4");

    return key;
}

public static byte[] intArrToByteArr(int[] input){

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(input.length * 4);
    IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
    intBuffer.put(input);

    byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();

    return array;
}

public static int[] byteArrToIntArr(byte[] input){

    IntBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
    int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
    intBuf.get(array);

    return array;
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;

    try {

        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Here's the normal jpeg file: http://postimg.org/image/m13xdbpi5/

Here's the encrypted one: http://postimg.org/image/dzsialsw1/

And here's the decrypted image: http://postimg.org/image/pm4pv01hb/

Comment: You are not encrypting a jpeg file to begin with. Instead you use bitmap factory to put it in a bitmap object upon you do all kind of pixel operations. That will not do but moreover not necessary. Better: just load the file from assets in a byte array. Then encode the byte array to another byte array. Save the second byte array to file. The way back is: load the encrypted file in a byte array. Decrypt to again another byte array. Save that byte array to file as decrypted file. Result: The decrypted file is equal to the file in assets. By the way: please post a working third link.

Comment: Doing this way the result will not be a real image file fomat like JPEG. The file will not show up an encrypted image if opened. What I want is just encrypt the pixels (JPEG content) and not all the file content like headers and etc.

Comment: By the way, the last link posted is not wrong. Just replace the characters of the above links.

Comment: You claim that you encrypt the image, but `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods are not actually used.

Comment: Ok. Now i understand what you want. Than listen to John Skeet. Please post a full working link. Second request. Realise how difficult it is on a phone to copy and paste. Dont ask your readers to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You're encrypting, but then saving the result as a JPEG. That's a lossy format - after loading it again, you'll end up with an image which is *visually similar* to the original, but may well have some different pixels... which means it won't decrypt back to the original pixels.

You should check that you can encrypt/decrypt *without* re-encoding the values as an image. If that much works, then you know the encryption isn't the problem... but you'll still have the issue of losing information when you encode it as a JPEG...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There's no way for doing it?

Comment: @user3303112: Well not like that - there are no doubt some interesting ways of encrypting images, but they wouldn't be a matter of just "replace pixels with encrypted pixels and save in a lossy format". You might want to find some research papers... or just encrypt the jpg file itself, and live with the fact that the encrypted data simply isn't an image.

Comment: Well, I really need it to be jpeg image file. I have seen this method: http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1208/1208.0999.pdf but it seems to be too much complex one. Anyway, I think this is a good poit to read.

Comment: @user3303112: You're inherently in a complex area - I don't think you're going to find a *simple* solution... or at least, not one that avoids blowing up the size of the JPEG massively. (If you could tweak your JPEG saving options, you *may* be able to make that lossless...)

Comment: There's something worse going on here than JPEG lossy-ness. My suspicion is signed/unsigned problems.

Comment: @user3344003: That's possible, which is why I recommended seeing whether the encryption worked *without* the image encoding. But the scheme is so fundamentally flawed that I figured I'd concentrate on the most important problem.

Comment: When I see hints of the image with apparent chaos, I suspect integer overflows/underflows.

Comment: @user3344003: But it's a visualization of encrypted data - I'd *expect* it to look like white noise, basically.

Comment: You have a decrypted one where you can make out the animal's shape but it is surrounded by noise.

Comment: @user3344003: Ah, I hadn't looked at that. Given the way encryption/decryption works, I'd expect small perturbations in the reloaded encrypted image to potentially make huge differences in the pixel values in the decrypted one, so I don't *think* this is necessarily evidence of a problem. It may be, but I don't think it necessarily is.